# Git in Dreamweaver: gitignore entire site minus a few specific files

Tags: git, dreamweaver, gitignore

I do a lot of work with CMS like Wordpress, joomla, Open Cart, etc. and I use Dreamweaver as my IDE for the most part.

DW now supports git, but I am having an issue with applying gitignore to most of the files in the local site. Especially in sub/sub/directories.
Ideally, I'd want to gitignore the entire site and then exclude the files in the template directory and the other few areas where I usually interact with the code.

Is there a way in gitignore itself to specify something like:
/directory/ all files (regardless of type)

In fact, it would be a nice thing to know in general when working with CMS frameworks where interaction is limited to a small subset of files and the rest of the files should be ignored.

And before you ask, yes, I could remove those files from my local copy of the server files, but often I need to have them locally as I need to trace or manage them, for instance in case of creating overrides in Joomla, I need to refer to the original file, then create a new file elsewhere to override it. My workflow usually requires that I keep the local and remote files synchronized also in case I need to run the site locally. Therefore a way to gitignore the entire site and then remove only a directory or two from gitignore would be really handy.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore whole directories by adding the directory on a new line in your .gitignore file:

```
foobar.js
ignored_directory
subs/ignored_sub_directory
subs/other_ignored_sub
```

I'm not sure how DW interfaces with their git implementation, but you should have no problem editing the file directly (it's plain text).